# Data - binding check boxes using Knockout JS

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a HTML table which has a column for checked rows(which has a check box in the cell).

I am using knockout to bind the selected check boxes to an observable array with an attribute ID as shown below.(this works fine without **"checked"**)

The **NListTable** is an observable array from **getJson** (which populate the table on return).I want to be able to post the selected IDs after the table is populated.

```
 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Generate Notice</b><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: SelectAll" /></th>
                            <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Name</b></th>
                            <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Application Number</b></th>
                            <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Right ID</b></th>
                       <th style=" text-align:center"><b> Division</b></th>
                        <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Use ID</b></th>
  </tr>
                    </thead>



      <tbody data-bind="foreach:NListTable">
                    <tr>

                        <td style=" text-align:center">

                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected">
                        </td>
                        <td style=" text-align:center">
                            <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style=" text-align:center">
                            <p data-bind="text:AppNum"></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style=" text-align:center">
                            <p data-bind="text:ID"></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style=" text-align:center">
                            <p data-bind="text:DivName"></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style=" text-align:center">
                            <p data-bind="text:useID"></p>
                        </td>
   </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

JS

```
function RowData(Name, AppNum, ID, DivName, useID) {
    var self = this;

    self.Selected = ko.observable(true);
    self.Name = ko.observable(Name);
    self.AppNum = ko.observable(AppNum);
    self.ID = ko.observable(ID);
    self.DivName = ko.observable(DivName);
    self.useID = ko.observable(useID);

}

self.NListTable = ko.observableArray([new RowData()]);
//self.selectedThings = ko.observableArray([]);

self.SelectAll = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.NListTable(), function (item) {
            return !item.Selected();
        });
        return item == null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.NListTable(), function (rowData) {
            rowData.Selected(value);
        });
    }
});
```

getJSON

```
 function (data) {

                $("#nListTable").show();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i] != null) {
                        self.NListTable.push(RowData(data[i].FirstName + ' ' + data[i].LastName, data[i].AppPre + '-' + data[i].AppNum, data[i].ID, data[i].DivName, data[i].useID));
                    }
                }

            });
```

I am trying to select all check boxes when the page loads by using the HTML attribute **"checked"** but this does not work all my check boxes are unchecked even when I use this.

How do I pre select all check boxes

Comment: You tell us "this works fine", but looking at your view code I'd doubt it. Could you update your question and include an actual repro of your scenario? Preferably use a Stack Snippet (see the editor toolbar) to make an actual runnable repro.

Comment: You should be having a computed for checkAll/Uncheck right ? so if you are trying to checkall on Load then assign `true` to that observable which in-turn checks all linked to computed. i'm guessing here . if you looking for something diff more info is appreciated

Comment: this piece of fiddle may be helpful try it http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/AneL9/106/

Comment: Can you add the part of view that has the for

Comment: Hi @supercool I am looking to have all the check boxes checked when the page loads and keep the binding!!

Comment: I still don't have any luck with the updated code.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can see here on load all checkboxes are checked . are they not ? forked your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/anel9/110/ . if you are looking for some otherthing explain us w.r.t fiddle here . cheers

Comment: It keeps throwing this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Selected' of undefined" at " return !item.Selected();"

Comment: I also added my getJSON call which populates the rows in the table.Is this causing the TypeError??

Comment: Hey I found the typo I had to declare the new Rowdata in the getJSON call  when pushing the rows now it works fine.@supercool please respond with the fiddle as answer so I can mark it down.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should be doing something like this

**View Model:**

```
self.SelectAll = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.NListTable(), function (item) {
            return !item.Selected();
        });
        return item == null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.NListTable(), function (rowData) {
            rowData.Selected(value);
        });
    }
});
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/anel9/110)**